# Showing an inequality for $\sin1$ using Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, taylor-expansion

> The inequality I'm trying to show is in the question below:
>   [image]

I'm able to do the first part of the question but I can't get to the inequality. The way I tried it was by saying that $-1<\cos{c_n}<1$ so for some $m \in \mathbb N$ we can say that $$1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-...+\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(2m-1)!}-\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}<\sin1<1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-...+\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(2m-1)!}+\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}$$ which further gives $$1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2m+1)(2m)-1}{(2m+1)!}<\sin1<1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2m+1)(2m)+1}{(2m+1)!}$$ and that's as far as I've gotten. I'm not sure if I've did something wrong or if I'm supposed to somehow simplify what I've got further into the form shown in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $n=2m$ and $n=2m-1$ and use $\cos(c_n) < 1$

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how I would use two $n$ values to show the inequality. Would I not have to just one value for $n$ and then find conditions for $c_n$ which give me the inequality?

Comment: The equality holds for all $n$. So you can put $n=2m$ and $n=2m-1$. Then use the fact that $0 < c_{2m-1}, c_{2m} < 1 \implies \cos(c_{n})<1$. For $n=2m$, you get the R.H.S., and for $n=2m-1$, you get the lower bound.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But how exactly did you know that you would have to use those two values for n and you couldn't just use one value for n? Is this just a standard trick?

Comment: @Hai I got the idea from $4m-1$ and $4m+1$ terms. For example, $2n+1=4m+1 \implies n=2m$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Take $n=2m$ then $n=2m-1$ and use $\cos(x)\le1$ to get the two inequalities.